# How to deal with concurrency and out of order messages when consuming from a message broker like RabbitMq?

Tags: architecture, rabbitmq, distributed-computing, masstransit

**The setup**
We're one team of many in a company which uses RabbitMq to signal business events happening. We have message consumers setup which consume all of the messages we care about but we run into two problems:

- Out of order messages (i.e. you get a new patient and a new treatment record and a new bill for this new patient but the plan and bill are consumed before the new patient event is consumed)
- Concurrency issues on writes (lets say two bills are added at the same time forcing you to update the patient's balance)

**Question**

So what is the best way to handle these problems? Seems like they must be common enough to have common solutions. We use C# and MassTransit for what it's worth.

**What we tried**
To handle OO messages we tried two things:

- Redeliver billing and treatment messages a couple of times hoping that eventually the patient will be added
- For one entity of the aggregate root we tried saving it regardless and then when the patient is created checking if it needs to be connected to any dependent entities

For concurrency issues we tried re-deliveries as well.

**What we found out**
Re-deliveries do not guarantee that the problem causing the re-delivery has gone away. Eventually we fail and the message goes into a dead-letter queue where it has to be manually examined. Sometimes a further manual re-delivery helps, but at that point the event was consumed way too late for SLAs and manual labour is involved. We've had wild cases with people getting a ton of related events, it's legal from the business logic perspective, i.e. a legitimate thing which can happen and we have to deal with.

No matter how much we increase the re-delivery count or delay, still something will get dead-lettered.

Persisting what you can when you get an event and then connecting things when this becomes possible complicates our message consumption logic immensely.

**What we are thinking about**
The next idea is to create a sort of a pipeline.

We can consume all messages and save them to a database. No re-deliveries, nothing in the dead-letter queue requiring manual intervention. Each message would have a patientId. Each treatment and bill would have a treatmentId, etc. That way we can do two things:

1. Process only events for entities which exist
2. Process all events for a given entity in a single batch resulting in only 1 write per entity with all the changes.

For example, old way we would do this:

1. Get bill B1 for a non existing treatment T1 and redeliver it
2. Get bill B2 for a non existing treatment T2 and redeliver it
3. Get treatment T1 for non existing patient P1 and redeliver it
4. Get patient P1 and persist him
5. Get bill B2 for non existing treatment T2 and redeliver it
6. Get bill B1 for non existing treatment T1 and redeliver it
7. Get treatment T1 and persist it
8. Get treatment T2 and fail to persist (concurrency issue on patient P1)
9. Get bill B2 for non existing treatment T2 and redeliver it
10. Get bill B1 for treatment T1 and persist it
11. Get treatment T2 and persist it
12. Get bill B2 for treatment T2 and persist it

In the new way we could do this:

1. Get bill B1 and persist the message
2. Get bill B2 and persist the message
3. Get treatment T1 and persist the message
4. Get patient P1 and persist the message
5. Get treatment T2 and persist the message
6. Processor queries unprocessed messages for new patient ids and finds P1
7. Processor fetches messages for creating P1, T1, B1 and B2, and T2
8. Processor calculates that he needs to do the following DB actions: Insert P1 with total outstanding balance B1.balance + B2.balance, Insert T1, T2, B1 and B2

No redeliveries, no concurrency issues, no out of order issues. If processor triggers before T2 message is persisted, then in step 7 we only insert p1, t1 and b1 and skip b2. Then in step 8 we update p1 and insert b1 and t1.

**Fears**
It's a lot of work. It's more complex. Outlier latency goes down but average latency increases. Feels like we're re-inventing the wheel. The reason why the patient has outstanding balances rather than querying bills which reference the patient is performance. Queries to the API have stringent SLAs, we should return this balance in the response. It was thought more performant to contiguously update the aggregate rather than querying related entities on the fly.

I fear we're reinventing the wheel and adding unnecesary complexity.

We can't get a sharding plugin added to Rabbit to shard on the patientId. We can't force the entire org to switch to Kafka, at least not in the next 12 months.

Comment: [Support](https://masstransit.io/support) is available, including on-demand architectural guidance on how to build distributed systems and tackle these sorts of challenges. With extensive history in the medical space across billing and operations, you'll likely find the best answers by talking with the experts.